# How to get original url from requests

Tags: python, python-requests

In doing the following:

```
>>> res=requests.get('http://www.hulu.com/return-of-the-one-armed-swordsman')
>>> res.url
u'http://www.hulu.com/watch/800769'
```

How would I get the original url that was called from `res`. That is, how would I get the `res` object to return `http://www.hulu.com/return-of-the-one-armed-swordsman`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`requests` keeps a history of redirect requests... Take the first entry from that...

```
import requests

res=requests.get('https://httpbin.org/status/301')
res.url
# https://httpbin.org/get
res.history[0].url
# https://httpbin.org/status/301
```

Note - you might want to cater for where no redirects occured, eg:

```
url = res.history[0].url if res.history else res.url
```

Of course -the other way is to just keep your URL in a variable and pass that to `requests.get` - then you know what you asked for to start with...

Comment: I think I'd prefer `(res.history + [res])[0].url`.

Comment: @Stefan sure, or even `(res.history or [res])[0].url` to avoid list concatenation if you really wanted to go down that route, but it's not exactly as easy to grok as the "conditional if" syntax (imho anyway)

Comment: Hmm, yeah, but that loses the meaning for me. I find `res.history + [res]` pretty clear, it's simply the complete history.

Comment: @Stefan true - but if you're not going to use it for that purpose - why build it? :)

Comment: But I *am* using it when I ask for the first entry of the complete history.